# secret detection in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, secret-key

I am facing a problem with secret detection rules in gitlab, since the predifined rules are not covering secrets in helm values yamls (secret,secretName,secretKeyRef...etc.). So I was hoping if somebody knows how to add rules to the predifined ones and what regex could help me do that?

I tried to use the below in secret-detection-ruleset.toml with no luck:

[secrets]

```
  description = 'secrets custom rules configuration'

  [[secrets.passthrough]]
    type  = "raw"
    target = "gitleaks.toml"
    value = """\
title = "gitleaks config"
# add regexes to the regex table
[[rules]]
id = "Secret Key Ref"
description = "Secret Key Ref"
regex = '''(?i)secret\s*:\s*'''
```

`

Would this regex do the trick?
regex = '''(?i)secret\s*:\s*'''

Appreciate any help